# session in asp.net core in memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

As I know in ASP.NET Core we can store a session in memory, in sql server or in redis.

On that website:
http://jiodev.com/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed
I have found the article:

> A distributed cache is shared by multiple app servers (see Caching Basics). >The information in the cache is not stored in the memory of individual web >servers, and the cached data is available to all of the app's servers.

As I understand I can use in memory distributed cache even if I have my application on multiple servers and I can share session? If yes then when to store session in sql server or redis?

Comment: When you actually get around to implementing it you should go with redis :) SQLServer is not a true memory cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An in-memory distributed cache is an oxymoron, unless you provide some way for the other servers in the cluster to connect to it and retrieve the cached data.

In your case, I think you could apply the simple rule:

- 1 Server = In Memory
- >1 Server = SQL Server or Redis (i.e. distributed).

If you re-read that article, I think you'll find that the two implementations of `IDistributedCache` talked about are SQL Server and Redis. There is no in-memory implementation of `IDistributedCache` and if there was, it would only be suitable for testing purposes.

Edit: As pointed out by ESG below, there *is* actually an in-memory implementation of `IDistributedCache`, but it is not actually a distributed cache, and as I stated above, is only useful for testing/development scenarios or where a distributed cache might be required in future.

Comment: as per [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed?view=aspnetcore-2.2#distributed-memory-cache): _The Distributed Memory Cache isn't an actual distributed cache. Cached items are stored by the app instance on the server where the app is running._

Comment: so how we can share sessions among same app hosted on multiple servers in load balanced scenario?

Comment: In-memory caches can still be useful in production multi-server scenarios when you can ensure session-affinity.